# PHP - Populate variables in an array from values in another array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

Hmmm how to explain? ;) I think I just let the crappy coding to the talking :)

Given an array of URL 'templates (truncated for ease of use)

```
$default = array(
    "/$market",
    "/$market/catalog/productsaz/",
    "/$market/catalog/products/$artid",
);
```

and a multidimensional array of markets (truncated for ease of use)

```
$markets = array(
array(market => "/gb/en", storeid => "storeId=1", langid =>"langId=-1", storenumber=> "001", prodid=> "12345", artid=> "4525412" ),
array(market => "/at/de", storeid => "storeId=2", langid =>"langId=-81", storenumber=> "003", prodid=> "12356", artid=> "8456125" ),
array(market => "/be/nl", storeid => "storeId=19", langid =>"langId=-13", storenumber=> "008", prodid=> "12367", artid=> "4578542" )
);
```

How do I blend the two together in order to get an array of resolved URL's for each market.

i.e.

```
/gb/en
/gb/en/catalog/productsaz/
/gb/en/catalog/products/4525412
/at/de
/at/de/catalog/productsaz/
/at/de/catalog/products/8456125
/be/nl
/be/nl/catalog/productsaz/
/be/nl/catalog/products/4578542
```

Of course array_merge seems the obvious choice, but I can't seem to work out how it would work in this case. So I did try a longer hand way, which while it is not efficient, seems like it should work to me but doesn't (the variables from the markets array don't seem to resolve)

Here is what I have so far:

```
function builder($clusterArray,$marketArray,$urlArray) {
if(isset($_POST['server'])) {
    $server = $_POST['server'];
    // DETERMINE THE CLUSTER
    $cluster=false;
    foreach($clusterArray as $n=>$c)
        if(in_array($server,$c)) {
            $cluster=$n;
            break;
        }
    print("Server=" . $server . "and cluster=" . $cluster); //DEBUG
    // DRAW THE TABLE
    //print("<table><tr><th>MARKET</th>");

    // LOOP THROUGH MARKETS AND IDS TO CREATE AN ARRAY OF URL'S 
    $urlsTohit = array();
    $baseurl = "http://$server";
    foreach($marketArray as $mkt) {
        $market = $mkt['market'];
        $storeid = $mkt['storeid'];
        $langid = $mkt['langid'];
        $storenumber = $mkt['storenumber'];
        $prodid = $mkt['prodid'];
        $artid = $mkt['artid'];
        foreach($urlArray as $template){
            array_push($urlsTohit,$baseurl . $template);        
        }
    }
    print_r($urlsTohit); //DEBUG
} else {
    print("Oops! Seems like you forgot to select a server. Please go back and choose a server before clicking on Go!");
}
}
```

EDIT: According to @Eugen Rieck I have updated my function to be:

```
function preSurfBuilder($clusterArray,$marketArray,$urlArray) {
if(isset($_POST['server'])) {
    $server = $_POST['server'];
    // DETERMINE THE CLUSTER
    $cluster=false;
    foreach($clusterArray as $n=>$c)
        if(in_array($server,$c)) {
            $cluster=$n;
            break;
        }
    print("Server=" . $server . "and cluster=" . $cluster); //DEBUG
    // DRAW THE TABLE
    //print("<table><tr><th>MARKET</th>");

    // LOOP THROUGH MARKETS AND IDS TO CREATE AN ARRAY OF URL'S 
    $baseurl = "http://$server";
    $result=array();
    foreach ($urlArray as $u) {
        foreach ($marketArray as $m) {
            $uu=$u;
            foreach ($m as $k=>$v)
                $uu=str_replace('$'.$k, $v, $uu);
            $result[]=$uu;
            }
        }
    print_r($result);
} else {
    print("Oops! Seems like you forgot to select a server. Please go back and choose a server before clicking on Go!");
}
}
```

and the output is something like (truncated):

```
Array ( [0] => / [1] => / [2] => / [3] => / [4] => / [5] => / [6] => / [7] => / [8] => / [9] => / [10] => / [11] => / [12] => / [13] => / [14] => / [15] => / [16] => / [17] => / [18] => / [19] => / [20] => / [21] => / [22] => / [23] => / [24] => / [25] => / [26] => / [27] => / [28] => / [29] => / [30] => / [31] => / [32] => / [33] => / [34] => / [35] => / [36] => / [37] => //catalog/productsaz/ [38] => //catalog/productsaz/ [39] => //catalog/productsaz/ [40] => //catalog/productsaz/ [41] => //catalog/productsaz/ [42] => //catalog/productsaz/ [43] => //catalog/productsaz/ [44] => //catalog/productsaz/ [45] => //catalog/productsaz/ [46] => //catalog/productsaz/ [47] => //catalog/productsaz/ [48] => //catalog/productsaz/ [49] => //catalog/productsaz/ [50] => //catalog/productsaz/ [51] => //catalog/productsaz/ [52] => //catalog/productsaz/ [53] => //catalog/productsaz/ [54] => //catalog/productsaz/ [55] => //catalog/productsaz/ [56] => //catalog/productsaz/ [57] => //catalog/productsaz/ [58] => //catalog/productsaz/ [59] => //catalog/productsaz/ [60] => //catalog/productsaz/ [61] => //catalog/productsaz/ [62] => //catalog/productsaz/ [63] => //catalog/productsaz/ [64] => //catalog/productsaz/ [65] => //catalog/productsaz/ [66] => //catalog/productsaz/ [67] => //catalog/productsaz/ [68] => //catalog/productsaz/ [69] => //catalog/productsaz/ [70] => //catalog/productsaz/ [71] => //catalog/productsaz/ [72] => //catalog/productsaz/ [73] => //catalog/p
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$result=array();
foreach ($default as $d) {
  foreach ($markets as $m) {
    $dd=$d;
    foreach ($m as $k=>$v)
      $dd=str_replace('$'.$k, $v, $dd);
    $result[]=$dd;
  }
}

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Edit: Fixed an thinko ($dd vs $d)

Comment: BTW the result is '//gb/en' and friends (double slash at the start): Your default has '/$market' (one slash) and $market has "/gb/en" (second slash). You need to remove on in your data.

Comment: I removed the initial slash from the market definitions. Thanks! Still not resolving right though

Comment: I tested with your data and it worked, did you change `$default=array("/$market", ...)` to `$default=array('/$market', ...)`or `$default=array("/\$market", ...)` as it is necessary?

Comment: Brilliant :) It works... I really appreciate your time and patience! If  I could give you two correct answers I would! And so much more elegant than my original solution :) THANKS!